MapStruct Ambiguous constructors
I have a problem using MAPSTRUCT. I created a record that has an id of type long and in my mapper I need to convert this object to the Long type, but the error below occurs. I will leave the code to make the problem clearer, sorry if any information is missing, it's my first question on the forum.
Ambiguous constructors found for creating java.lang.Long: Long(long), Long(java.lang.String). Either declare parameterless constructor or annotate the default constructor with an annotation named @Default.
My code:
IdClient.java
public record IdClient(Long id) { }
ClientEntity.java
@Table(name = "client") @Builder 
public record ClientEntity(Long idClient){} 
ClientMapper.java
@ApplicationScoped public interface ClientMapper { 
ClientEntity IdClientToClientEntity(IdClient id);
Long map(IdClient id);
}

Does this answer your question? "Ambiguous constructors found" error when there more than one constructor when using MapStruct

I tried to apply the suggestions from this topic, but it didn't work out. The issue with creating a default annotation is that the problematic constructor belongs to the Long class from Java itself. Due to the existence of two constructors, one that receives the String parameter and another of type Long, when I pass my record, which is of type long (it has a long attribute called id), it doesn't identify this.

I solved it, @Mapping(target = "idRelatorio", source = "id") but I'm not sure if this is the most appropriate way, considering that the record is of type long and my entity expects a long. I opened this topic to find out what would be the best approach for this case.
